# Can Anyone tell me how to parse JSON object with different key IOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, json

The Json Object here Comment has different keys like 1,2,3,4. Usually A Json Object has same key like in the inner part important,isgoal, minute etc. If i can parse 1,2,3,4 then it will be easy to parse important, isgoal, minute. But the problem is I can't get the objects 1,2,3,4. IOS throws Invalid key exception.....

Here's the Part of Json object---

- comm_commentaries: {

  - comment: {

    - 1: { 
       important: "False", 
       isgoal: "False",
       minute: "90'",
       comment: "Attempt missed. Eliaquim Mangala (Manchester City) header from the centre of the box misses to the left. Assisted by Jesús Navas with a cross following a corner.",
       id: "8429441"
      },
    - 2: {
       important: "False",
       isgoal: "False",
       minute: "90'",
       comment: "Corner, Manchester City. Conceded by Shaun Wright-Phillips.",
       id: "8429402"
      },
    - 3: {
       important: "False",
       isgoal: "False",
       minute: "90'",
       comment: "Attempt blocked. Wilfried Bony (Manchester City) right footed shot from the centre of the box is blocked. Assisted by Yaya Touré.",
       id: "8429401"
       },
    - 4: {
       important: "True",
       isgoal: "True",
       minute: "87'",
       comment: "Goal! Manchester City 6, Queens Park Rangers 0. David Silva (Manchester City) right footed shot from very close range to the bottom right corner. Assisted by Wilfried Bony with a through ball.",
       id: "8429400"
       },

    }
    }

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: The Json Object here Comment has different keys like 1,2,3,4. Usually A Json Object has same key like in the inner part important,isgoal, minute etc. If i can parse 1,2,3,4 then it will be easy to parse important, isgoal, minute. But the problem is I can't get the objects 1,2,3,4. IOS throws Invalid key exception..... Please help

Comment: That improved the question.  The answer is that the JSON is invalid.  The keys must be strings.  The best solution would involve fixing this at the source.  However this almost-JSON is being generated, try to repair that so it provides valid JSON.

Comment: @danh If this is NSLog() output the quotes are stripped by the description method. A bad choice by Apple, Swift does the display correctly.

Comment: @zaph - plausible, but the OP states that the parse fails.  This is presumably just a string input to a failing parse.

Comment: OK but the OP does not show the parseing code that is failing. @Shawon91Sust please add the failing parsing code to the question.

Comment: Yeah.  Still close-worthy, I guess.  @Shawon91Sust - do you see why folks are having trouble rendering assistance?

Comment: If you're using swift I recommend the [ObjectMapper library](https://github.com/Hearst-DD/ObjectMapper).

Comment: Read the documentation for NSDictionary.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you are using the number `1` as the key, you should use a string `@"1"`, please post the parsing copde that is failing. `NSDictionary` keys must be objects that implement `NSCopying` and are most commonaly `NSStrings`.

`NSLog()` output of `NSDictionaries` uses the description` method which omits the quotes when not needed. This makes understanding the output more difficult.

```
NSString *isgoal = jsonObject[@"comm_commentaries"][@"comment"][@"1"][@"isgoal"]
NSString *minute = jsonObject[@"comm_commentaries"][@"comment"][@"1"][@"minute"]
```